# Filter csv file according to null values using azure data factory

Tags: azure, csv, azure-data-factory

I am having a CSV file in blob now I wanted to push that CSV file into SQL table using azure data factory but want I want is to put a check condition on CSV data if any cell has null value so that row data will copy into an error table like for an example I have ID, name and contact column in CSV so for any record lets say contact is null(1, 'Gaurav', NULL) so in that case, this row will insert into an error table and if there is no null in the row then that row will go into the master table

**Note:** As the sink is SQL on a VM so we can't create any this over there we have to handle this on data factory level only

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using a mapping data flow in ADF. One way of doing it is to use a derived column with an expression that that does the null check with for example the isNull() function. That way you can populated a new column with some value for the different cases, which you can then use in a conditional split to redirect the different streams to different sinks.

Comment: I know but actually in data flows it is taking time to on the cluster because we are taking data from event trigger so when ever someone upload file in blob trigger will work that why I wanted to do without data flows

Comment: Pipelines are just orchestrators, so if you want to do row level work, you need something other than a standard data factory pipeline: Azure Batch, DataBricks, DataFlow, etc.

Comment: You can emulate row-wise operations on a small dataset by doing a lookup followed by a filter activity. You can use Logic Functions to check the values inside the rows in the filter activity.